# VBA macro to change color of cell that changes value for 1 second

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working on Excel Project and I am dealing with prices that are changing live and are taken from external source in column E and F.

What I want is :

1. When These cells Change value, I want them to Change its Color from orange to lets say White, or Change cell Background to White
2. I want this to happen only for 1 second or less, and to revert back to original cell Color or Background Color

This way I can Keep my eye on prices when they Change.

Is this possible ?

Please help. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into the code of the worksheet you want it to apply to (not in a seperate module) for a 1 second colour change when any cell in column E or F changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:F")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Application.Wait (Now + #0:00:01#)
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    End If
End Sub
```

Or for less than 1 second change, use the version below as `application.wait` doesn't handle times any finer than 1 second, but `timer` does.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:F")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim x As Single
        x = Timer
            While Timer - x < 0.5
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Wend
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 46
    End If
End Sub
```

The ColorIndex values are for white and default orange. To change to the particular colors you're looking for, see http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

EDIT - New answer below. Original answer above.

Ok, this is a bit of a messy way around it but should achieve what you're looking to do.

Paste this into a module, adjusting the 1 to 10 to cover the number of cells you're watching for changes in:

```
Public val(1 To 10) As Variant
```

Paste this into your ThisWorkbook code area, adjusting the cell references so every ref you're watching is included in the correct ascending order (Column E lowest to highest, then Column F lowest to highest):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    val(1) = Sheet1.Range("E1").Value
    val(2) = Sheet1.Range("E2").Value
    val(3) = Sheet1.Range("E3").Value
    val(4) = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
    val(5) = Sheet1.Range("E5").Value
    val(6) = Sheet1.Range("F1").Value
    val(7) = Sheet1.Range("F2").Value
    val(8) = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value
    val(9) = Sheet1.Range("F4").Value
    val(10) = Sheet1.Range("F5").Value
End Sub
```

Finally, paste this into the code area of the sheet with the values you're watching for changes, again adjusting the ranges to fit your watch range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim x As Single, colIndx As Integer
i = 1

    For Each cell In Range("E1:E5")
        If cell.Value <> val(i) Then
            colIndx = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
            x = Timer
            While Timer - x < 0.5
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Wend
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colIndx
            val(i) = cell.Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("F1:F5")
        If cell.Value <> val(i) Then
            colIndx = cell.Interior.ColorIndex
            x = Timer
            While Timer - x < 0.5
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Wend
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = colIndx
            val(i) = cell.Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Finally save and close your workbook and re-open it and hopefully the colours should update along with the values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I added the code, but it seems to work only when I click on cell and Change its Color. When it Auto updates new prices it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: The worksheet change event only fires when the actual values on the sheet change. I presume that your values are auto updating via a formula of some kind? If you can post some detail on the mechanism by which the price values are updating I can see if there's another method I can think of to higlight the changes.

Comment: Yes, there is a formula used which takes values from column Headlines and Returns exact prices. So, formula doesnt Change, only values. It is same if I write formula on E10 column , for example, this =A10. And if i write on a10 , lets say, 1000 and Change it to 1500, nothing will happen on E10. value will Change, but Background Color will not.

Comment: Updated my answer with something that may work for you - although not a particularly elegant solution.

Comment: You are Genius, thank you so much !!! It works. Just one more question, I already have each 2nd row different black and Grey shade Color, so I would like it to remain like that. When value changes, Background changes Color to White (same as now) and after that it Returns to original color. Is it possible or I have to assign each cell a same Color index ? Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Yep, that's do-able. We simply assign the original ColorIndex value to a variable before we change it and then use the variable to change it back when we're done. Answer updated.